# Cloud Function to push data into a storage bucket works in testing environment but not in production

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I am having issues with a cloud function that simply creates a pandas dataframe and pushes it to a google storage bucket. The function works as expected when I open the source editor and test it. But when I deploy the function and trigger it via pub/sub, the function crashes and gives the error

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_bucket?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: [my-project]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.buckets.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).

This error does not occur when testing the cloud function in the Cloud Shell testing environment.

Here is my python source code for the cloud function:

```
import base64
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """

    df_to_push = pd.DataFrame(data = [{"greeting" : "hello"}])

    bucket_name = "my_bucket"
    GCS_CLIENT = storage.Client()
    print(GCS_CLIENT.SCOPE)
    bucket = GCS_CLIENT.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    blob_name = 'app_data/my_data.csv'
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(df_to_push.to_csv(), 'text/csv')
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

At first I thought that the function was grabbing the wrong client information so I printed out the client scope, which returns the following in both testing and deployment environments:

> ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')

This is once again what I expected because I granted the service account those accesses. The clients are the same in testing and deployment, yet only in testing does the function successfully push the dataframe to the bucket. What am I getting wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: is the bucket hardcoded in the function? If so, and if you deploy the code in different project, did you change the bucket name for a bucket in the same project as your deployment? it's a permission issue, your Cloud Function runtime service account does not have access to your bucket. Investigate this way, you should find your mistake!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you so much for the comment! I changed the runtime service account and now it is working.